# CSS styling WordPress widget

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am showing language translation flags on my Wordpress website:

Below is the code

```
<ul>
<li id="qtranslate-8" class="widget-container widget_qtranslate">
<ul class="qtrans_language_chooser" id="qtranslate-8-chooser">
<li class="lang-en active">    
<a href="http://www.fadomi.org/" hreflang="en" title="English" class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_en"><span style="display:none">English</span></a>
</li>
<li class="lang-fr">
<a href="http://www.fadomi.org/fr/" hreflang="fr" title="Français" class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_fr"><span style="display:none">Français</span></a></li>
<li class="lang-zh">
<a href="http://www.fadomi.org/zh/" hreflang="zh" title="中文" class="qtrans_flag qtrans_flag_zh"><span style="display:none">中文</span></a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="qtrans_widget_end"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

This is showing me a list with bullets..as you can see on fadomi.org, I want to remove these bullets and show all these flags horizontally, Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove bullets from an unordered list:

```
ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

You may also want to reset the left margin:

```
ul { margin-left: 0; }
```

Then you can float list elements to show them horizontally:

```
ul li { float: left; }
```

And finally, clear the float:

```
ul { clear: left; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `ul {list-style:none}` in your css.

You have

```
ul {
list-style: square;
margin: 0px 0px 18px 1.5em;
}
```

Remove `square` and add `none`.

Answer (score 1):

Write this in CSS -

```
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul li{
  float: left; 
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/juUaP/)

Comment: @PhillipMclauren Can you share the URL?

Comment: fadomi.org Its just showing weird..my menu is also misplaced..they were just right to the logo before..but now they are just mounted top. Please look at this